# Magento2 | The use of function getallheaders(), base64_decode(), rawurldecode() is discouraged

Tags: magento2, phpcs, magento-coding-standard

The use of function getallheaders(), base64_decode(), rawurldecode()  is discouraged. What are the alternative for these in Magento2

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use `\Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface::decode`  instead of `base64_decode` and `rawurldecode` ([code source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ea236e7fb75864ed7e03ba5ad1149f77ff4bfb26/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Url/Decoder.php#L32-L36)).

And for HTTP Headers Magento have class `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header` ([code source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ea236e7fb75864ed7e03ba5ad1149f77ff4bfb26/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Header.php#L10)).

Comment: Thanks for the help Leonid, I don't have enough reputation to upvote.